# Why this code's result is 789-123-456- 456- 456?

Tags: java, printf

```java
System.out.printf("%3$d-%3d-%2$d-%<4d-%5d %n", 123, 456, 789);
```

My prediction of this code was

```
789-123-456- 456-  789
```

But the actual result was

```
789-123-456- 456-  456
```

Why does `%5d` take `456`?

Answer (score 2):

Because you used flag `<` which reused previous argument index, which is 2 hence the number 465.

For more information refer [java.util.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) documentation.

**Argument Index**
The argument index is a decimal integer indicating the position of the argument in the argument list. The first argument is referenced by "1$", the second by "2$", etc.

Another way to reference arguments by position is to use the '<' ('\u003c') flag, which causes the argument for the previous format specifier to be re-used. For example, the following two statements would produce identical strings:

```
   Calendar c = ...;
   String s1 = String.format("Duke's Birthday: %1$tm %1$te,%1$tY", c);

   String s2 = String.format("Duke's Birthday: %1$tm %<te,%<tY", c);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [`Formatter` JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html), Section "Argument Index":

> Format specifiers can reference arguments in three ways:

> - *Explicit indexing* is used when the format specifier contains an argument index.
> - *Relative indexing* is used when the format specifier contains a '<' ('\u003c') flag which causes the argument for the previous format specifier to be re-used.
> - *Ordinary indexing* is used when the format specifier contains neither an argument index nor a '<' flag. Each format specifier which uses ordinary indexing is assigned a sequential implicit index into argument list which is independent of the indices used by explicit or relative indexing.

Your format string "%3$d-%3d-%2$d-%<4d-%5d %n" consumes the arguments in the following order:

- `%3$d` uses explicit indexing to reference the third argument (789)
- `%3d` uses ordinary indexing to reference the first argument (123)
- `%2$d` uses explicit indexing to reference the second argument (456)
- `%<4d` uses relative indexing to reference the second argument again
- `%5d` uses ordinary indexing to reference the second argument (456)

Your question on why `%5d` references the second argument can be answered like this: it references the second argument because it is the second format specifier that uses *ordinary indexing*.